# Numerical Analysis, Quarteroni 8.9.3

Tags: polynomials, summation, numerical-methods

Prove that $w_{n+1}'(x_i) = \prod_{j=0,j\neq i}(x_i - x_j)$ where $w_{n+1}$ is the nodal polynomial (8.6). Then, check (8.5).

Background information:

It can be checked that $$\prod_n(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}\frac{w_{n+1}(x)}{(x-x_i)w_{n+1}'(x_i)}y_i \ \ \ (8.5)$$ where $w_{n+1}$ is the nodal polynomial of degree $n+1$ defined as $$w_{n+1}(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-x_i) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (8.6)$$

Attempted proof:

We have $$l_i(x) = \prod_{j=0,j\neq i}^{n}\frac{(x-x_j)}{x_i-x_j)}$$ and $$w_{n+1}(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-x_i)$$ I am not sure where to go from here, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Just compute $w_{n+1}'(x)$ using the product rule and then set $x=x_i$.

An example will show how this works. Let's take $n=2$. Then $w_3(x)=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ and $w_3'(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(x-x_0)(x-x_2)+(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$.

In the general case, $w_{n+1}'(x)$ is a sum of $n+1$ terms, all but one of which contain the factor $x-x_i$ for a fixed choice of $i$. The factor that does not is the product of all $x-x_j$ with $j\ne i$. Hence the result.

Comment: Could you show me, I know it is trivial for you but I am not sure how to use the product rule in this case

Comment: @MorganWeiss, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
w_{n+1}'(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n\prod_{j=0,j\ne i}^{n}(x-x_j)
$$
So
$$
w_{n+1}'(x_i) = \prod_{j=0,j\ne i}^{n}(x_i-x_j)
$$
And
$$
l_i(x) = \prod_{j=0,j\neq i}^{n}\frac{(x-x_j)}{(x_i-x_j)}=\frac{\prod_{j=0,j\neq i}^{n}(x-x_j)}{w_{n+1}'(x_i)}=\frac{w_{n+1}(x)}{(x-x_i)w_{n+1}'(x_i)}
$$
Thus
$$
\prod_n(x) =\sum_{i = 0}^{n}l_i(x)y_i= \sum_{i = 0}^{n}\frac{w_{n+1}(x)}{(x-x_i)w_{n+1}'(x_i)}y_i \ \ \ (8.5)
$$